# Failing Transaction within Truffle Testing

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

How does one test a transaction that is supposed to fail when testing with truffle?

For example, say I was testing an ERC token, in which **accounts[0]** had a balance of 20. Within a test, I call **ERC.transfer(accounts[1], 25, {from: accounts[0]})**, hoping to make sure that this would fail. How would I confirm that it did fail?

Sure, I could check that the balances of **accounts[0]** and **accounts[1]** do not change - but it seems like there may be a more elegant way to do so. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [gist](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/helpers/expectThrow.js) can help you

```
export default async promise => {
  try {
    await promise;
  } catch (error) {
    // TODO: Check jump destination to destinguish between a throw
    //       and an actual invalid jump.
    const invalidJump = error.message.search('invalid JUMP') >= 0;
    // TODO: When we contract A calls contract B, and B throws, instead
    //       of an 'invalid jump', we get an 'out of gas' error. How do
    //       we distinguish this from an actual out of gas event? (The
    //       testrpc log actually show an 'invalid jump' event.)
    const outOfGas = error.message.search('out of gas') >= 0;
    assert(
      invalidJump || outOfGas,
      "Expected throw, got '" + error + "' instead",
    );
    return;
  }
  assert.fail('Expected throw not received');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my truffle-assertions library to test for reverts or other failures.

It can be installed with npm:

```
npm install truffle-assertions
```

And then imported at the top of your file:

```
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
```

You can then use it inside your tests like this:

```
// when you want to test revert
truffleAssert.reverts(ERC.transfer(accounts[1], 25, {from: accounts[0]}));

// or general failure
truffleAssert.fails(ERC.transfer(accounts[1], 25, {from: accounts[0]}));
```

The full method documentation can be found on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-assertions).